# Move .ass subtitles below the video

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I am watching a show in 1920x960 format on my 1920x1080 screen in VLC player, with subtitles coming from an .ass file. This is what it looks like:

[image: PlayResv = 960, MarginV = 0]

I would like to move the subtitles into the black margin below the actual video. This is the preamble of the .ass file when opened in Notepad++:

```
[Script Info]
ScriptType: v4.00+
Collisions: Normal
PlayResX: 1920
PlayResY: 960
Timer: 100.0
WrapStyle: 0

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,sans-serif,20,&H00FFFFFF,&H00FFFFFF,&H000F0F0F,&H000F0F0F,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0.00,1,2,3,2,20,20,0,0
```

I tried to decrease the `MarginV` parameter, i.e. the second-to-last number in the last line:

```
[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,sans-serif,20,&H00FFFFFF,&H00FFFFFF,&H000F0F0F,&H000F0F0F,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0.00,1,2,3,2,20,20,-10,0
```

This does indeed move the subtitles down, but unfortunately they're cut off instead of extending into the black region:

[image: PlayResY = 960, MarginV = -10]

Increasing the `PlayResY` parameter to `1080`, which feels like it should fix this, changes nothing and produces the same moved down but cut off subtitles.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You have to pad the image before you can move subs below it, you can't just move them to what is, in effect,  a non-screen area - there's a how-to here which is  far too much to precis into an answer - https://www.vlchelp.com/how-to-change-subtitle-position-in-vlc/ tbh, it's too much faff to worry about :P